# Why would *My Computer* security zone be added to a user?

Tags: audit

Normally we have just 4 security zones listed under the security tab in *Internet Options*.  For some reason, a 5th security zone, called *My Computer* is being added to various users, seemly at random.  It has become quite a nuisance as it locks down the user from being able to run various applications on their computer or through the network.

We have a registry fix, but we would really like to track down what is causing it to happen in the first place.  We've looked through our *Group Policies*, but can not find any anomalies that would activate this extra zone.

Here's what the security tab normally displays:

[image: Normal Security Tab]

And here's what an affected users security tab looks like:

[image: My Computer added Security Zone]

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2012/06/05/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-security-zone-sites-using-group-polices/